# Confusion with ACTCHL, MAXCHL, MAXCHANNELS and MAXACTIVECHANNELS from WMQ

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

i'm kind of confused with the relationship among `ACTCHL, MAXCHL, MAXCHANNELS and MAXACTIVECHANNELS`. Is property `ACTCHL` same with `MAXACTIVECHANNELS`, and `MAXCHL` with `MAXCHANNELS`?  In addition, what's the default value for them? i can see either **100** or **200**, not sure which one is correct.

Thanks

i just find `ACTCL` and `MAXCHL` are for z/OS, but `MAXCHANNELS` and `MAXACTIVECHANNELS` are for open system. It's clear. However, please help answer the default value question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough, the best reference for these is in the WMQ Explorer manual rather than the WMQ manual.  The tables in the [*Queue Manager Properties*](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/e_properties_qmanager.htm) topic list the settings, their default values and in some cases the relationship between them.  When you get there use your browser search for the specific attributes (i.e. MAXACTIVECHANNELS) because the tales are organized based on tabs in WMQ Explorer rather than strict alphabetical sequence.

Comment: i got it there. Thanks @T.Rob

Comment: I agree and I often use MQ Explorer reference for help.